# Storing a value of a variable in a text file

Tags: javascript, php, html, variables, storage

I have created a simple mechanism to grab a persons First and Last name (this is of course the very basic code). However I want to write the value of a variable to a text file. I have used some php, however it does not seem to work:

```html
<?php $handle = fopen("log.txt", "a");
foreach($_GET as $variable => $value) {
fwrite($handle, $variable);
fwrite($handle, "=");
fwrite($handle, $value);
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
}
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
fclose($handle);
exit;
?>
```

Therefore, I was wondering if there was any of code I could use to place this information into the text file? Your help is appreciated.

Initial code:

```html
<head>
<script>

      function getDetails()
      {
        var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName");
 var nameElement = document.getElementById("lastName");
        var theName = firstName.value;
 var theLastName = lastName.value;
        document.getElementById("someDiv").innerHTML += theName += theLastName;
 

  }
  </script>
</head>

<html>

  <div id="someDiv">
   Details:
  </div>

  <br><br>

  <input id="firstName" type="text">
 <input id="lastName" type="text">
  <input type="button" value="Go!" onClick="getDetails();">

  <br>    
</html>
```

I would however prefer Javascript.

Comment: Do you mean Java or JavaScript?

Comment: Javascript :-) @khelwood

Answer (score 0):

To write on a file via php, you can use the [file_put_content()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) function.

Here's a simple code example:

```
// The file where to write
$file = 'db.txt';
// The content
$file_content = $your_variable;
// Write the content
file_put_contents($file, $file_content);
```

You can also append content to the file:

```
// The file where to write
$file = 'db.txt';
// Old content
$file_content = file_get_contents($file);
// Old + new content
$file_content .= $your_variable;
// Write the content
file_put_contents($file, $file_content);
```

You can also append to a file file_put_contents flags:

```
// The file where to write
$file = 'db.txt';
// New content
$file_content = $your_variable;
// Write the content
file_put_contents($file, $file_content, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
// FILE_APPEND: used to append the new contents at the end of the file
// LOCK_EX : used to avoid another user to write on the same file at the same time
```

Comment: Yes, file_put_content() is easier to use for a beginner in my opinion.